# Find the common ratio of geometric progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

If $p,q$, and $r$ are terms of an arithmetic progression are also in a geometric  progression, then find  the common ratio of the geometric progression in terms of $p,q$, and $r$.

Comment: I considered First term as 'a' and common difference as 'd'. And Pth term as a + (p-1)d .And similarly q and r.

Comment: And then i did q^2=p * r.  But i dont know how to eliminate a and d.Since there is only one equation.

Comment: I also do not know if ([tag:sequences-and-series]) is the proper tag, but I think it's a better fit than ([tag:calculus]). If anyone has a better idea for a tag, feel free to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Let $p,q,r$ be the terms.  Let $x$ be the ratio in the geometric progression, $y$ be the increment in the arithmetic progression.  $x=\frac qp, y=q-p$ Then the terms are $p, px, px^2$ and also $p, p+y, p+2y$. Can find two equations for $x$ and $y$?

Added:  You have $p+y=px, p+2y=px^2$.  We have two equations in two unknowns if we regard $p$ as a parameter.  Subtracting, $y=px^2-px$.  Dividing, $x=\frac rq=\frac {p+2y}{p+y}$.  I suspect the desired answer is the solution for $x$ of these two.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that $p,q$, and $r$ are adjacent terms in each progression?

Comment: Ya..i think the same..they are not necessarily adjacent terms.

Comment: @JavaMan:  Absolutely.  But without that, I don't think there is an answer.

Comment: @anna:  see above-I can't ping two people with one comment.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @RossMillikan what i tried i have put in the comment.Please let me know if i am approaching correct.

Comment: If p,q,r are adjacent terms, then the common ratio is $\frac{p}{q}$. I suspect they need not be adjacent, and perhaps some information is missing from the problem...